# Can the visual studio team services extension sdk be used to alter work item events

Tags: azure-devops

Can a vsts extension be created to alter a work item event?

Example: I want to block or not allow a work item to move from specific state to another. If a user changes a work item from state New to Closed, I would like to stop the change.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such an extension in marketplace so far.

But for similar work around (after saving a WIT, rewrite the state as before, not block), you can create your own extension by using [related events](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-workitem-extension#events).

In your extension, you can get the work item fields firstly. Then you can call **onSaved** event, after the save operation, you can rewrite all fields with original values (such as by [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#update-work-items)).

There are some extension examples for [workItemPage](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/work-item-form/workItemPage.html) and [a work item watch dog](http://nocture.dk/2016/01/02/lets-make-a-visual-studio-team-services-extension/) for you to refer.